# How do I make a calculated field for total cost by quarter and location in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have Tableau 9.1 and have the costs per transaction in a column over the course of 3 years. I also have the dates and locations for all the transactions.

How do i make a calculated field for total cost at a location for a given quarter assigned to each observation?

Answer (score 0):

Generally that depends on how you want to display these values.

An easy way would be via a LOD calculation:

```
{fixed DATETRUNC('quarter',[Date]), [Location]: SUM([Cost])}
```

This calculates the `SUM([Cost])` for each quarter of `[Date]` and each `[Location]`